# Числовой тип в json

Tags: json

[Говорится](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp), что допустимыми типами для json являются:

- строка
- число
- объект (JSON-объект)
- массив
- boolean
- null

При этом я не вижу пояснения, какое именно число имеется в виду.

Javascript для чисел использует double. Означает ли это, что json тоже предполагает double? Корректно ли записывать как числа целые числа, выходящие за пределы int53? А дробные, превосходящие точность double?

Что такие числа будут означать **с точки зрения формата** - будет ли неявно предполагаться округление?

```
{
  "int64": 1000000000000000001,
  "decimal": 1000000000000000001.5
}
```

Comment: наверно не имеет значение какое число, хоть дробное хоть целочисленное, но это число и оно будет числом если написать именно число без кавычек....